# why reference is not a object,but it can be used with &?

Tags: c++, reference

like this code

```
int i = 42;
int *p = &i;
int *&r = p;
*r = 0;
```

The `r` is reference and is not a object, so why it can be used with `*`.

Comment: `r` is a reference to an `int*` so its `operator*` is that of the referenced `int*`. Please read your example carefully.

Comment: It's a reference to a pointer, and works like all other references. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: An `int` is an object.  A *pointer* is an object.  A `int*` is a pointer, which is an object.  An `int*&` is a reference to an object, the object it references is a pointer.

Comment: Think of a reference as an alias (alternative name of an object). Any operation(s) performed on the reference are applied to the object it is an alias for.

Comment: A reference can be used the very same way as the referenced object can be used. If the referenced object is a pointer, it can be used with `*`.

Answer (score 1):

> why reference is not a object

Because the that's how references are specified in the language.

> The "r" is reference and is not a object,so why is can be used with "*".

Because the object that `r` refers to is a pointer, and you can use a pointer as an operand  to the unary `*` operator.

Answer (score 0):

A reference can be bound to things other than objects. Remember that a pointer is also an object. So a reference can be bound to a pointer too, or to even another reference. See for yourself with some throwaway code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T& t){
        std::cout << t << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    int object = 1;
    int* pointer = &object;
    int& reference = object;
    int*& reference_to_pointer = pointer;
    
    Foo<int> o1(object); // passing 'object' by reference
    Foo<int*> o2(pointer); // passing a pointer to 'object' by reference
    Foo<int&> o3(reference); // passing the reference to 'object' by reference
    Foo<int*&> o4(reference_to_pointer); // passing a reference to a pointer to 'object' by reference
}
```